# Textview being overlapped by Imageview

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, imageview

So I have a textview that I placed above an imageview. When I add text to the textview it is covered up by the imageview. What I want to happen is that when I add more text to the textview the imageview is pushed further down starting below the end of the text. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Heres my activity_route_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zach.listview.RouteDetails">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<com.example.zach.listview.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/routeImage"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and heres my routeDetails.java

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class RouteDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

TouchImageView routeImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

    //back button for route details view
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //TextView for route details
    final TextView routeDetailsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeDetailsView);
    routeDetailsView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("route"));

    //ImageView for route details
    routeImage = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.routeImage);
    routeImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("imageResourceId", 0));

}

//back button for route details view
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    finish();
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

`android:layout_below="@+id/routeDetailsView"`

to

`<com.example.zach.listview.TouchImageView` definition in `xml`.

Something like this:

```
<com.example.zach.listview.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/routeImage"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_below="@id/routeDetailsView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
```

Comment: thanks that works perfect. But now i'm having an issue where instead of the imageview getting pushed down and the page becoming scrollable the image is just shrinking down on the same screen

Comment: Try change `android:adjustViewBounds="false"` to `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: Or use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code inside `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks that worked. but now my image zooming and scrolling is really goofy.